# Watch file for changes in package without using api.add_files()

Tags: meteor, stylus

I have some stylus mixins in a Meteorite package that I don't want to add with `api.add_files()`. Instead, they need to be `@import`ed into an app from the packages directory to access the mixins. However, Meteor will not watch these files for changes, making development and testing a little annoying (either the server needs to be restarted, or an added file needs to be changed).

Is there any way to make Meteor watch a file for changes, even if it is not directly included in the app/package?

Comment: Why can't you use add_files? If the extension is getting picked up by Meteor, try a different extension.

Comment: @matb33 Meteor does pick the files via stylus and `@import` but it doesn't watch files not declared with .add_files for any changes it assumes they're not part of the package. Im having a bit of trouble with this too but I just added them all in with .add_files

Comment: @matb33 I have some variables in my stylus files that are declared with `?=` (default equals). Those variables are used to set some global styles. The idea was that the user can set those variables, then import the package stylus files so that they can override the global settings variables. I realized this isn't necessary for mixins, but it does appear to be necessary for regular styles that depend on variables. I suppose I can just define those regular styles as a mixin that the user would have to apply to their `body` style after setting their variables rather than using `@import`

Comment: @Akshat Yes that was pretty much my problem. I can add them to `add_files()` just for the `on_test` function which helps for testing. I may just refactor the stylus so everything is a mixin allowing users to override variables, and then I can use `add_files()` in `on_use`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming you're using a stylus smart package for this answer to make sense)

I suggest you take the same route as recommended for the LESS package: rename the files you want to `@import` to `.stylimport`, and do an `add_files` on those too.

Additionally, you can reference those `.stylimport` files from outside the smart package as such:

`@import "/packages/name-of-your-package/thefilename.stylimport"`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the correct way to do this. Interestingly, the LESS package actually registers `.lessimport` files with the dependency watcher, just not doing anything with them: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/less/plugin/compile-less.js - However, the Stylus package does no such thing for `.stylimport` files, so `.stylimport` files in an app (as opposed to a package) will not be watched for changes. Perhaps this is an oversight in the Stylus package?